# What is tantra yoga?

Tags: shiva, tantra

I don't think this yoga was mentioned in bhagavad gita, does it have any origin in the vedas?
This yoga is mostly associated with Shiva. 
It seems to me that there are at least two parts of hindu philosophy. One talks more about what the gita, uphanishades etc, and other is is more based on Shiva and his path.
So where does tantra yoga fit in all of this?

Comment: tantras are agamas. duplicate

Comment: Tantra Yoga, is the So called Left path has its origins in Kundalini Yoga or Shakthi Yoga, That is very real and sometimes dangerous to practice. But then as usual digressed and adopted to fit needs and corrupted over thousands of years... Some original excerpts are also there in Kashmiri Shaivism. You should also not stop at Tantra Yoga. There is a Third yoga called Achala Yoga...Very few adepts are aware.. Which is way more profound and is a real art...BG is very recent one and not much mention of these...and then there is always an *anuttara*...Self-learn what this is please...